# cant get data to group in find in a cakephp HABTM

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a HABTM relationship of Students and Subjects.  I simply want to display all the subjects associated with a student without repetition of student details. I dont want the student details to keep repeating in the data output. How do I get the student details as shown below to output once and then all the subjects associated with this student to output?

Group didnt work. I didnt see the answer in the docs but I am sure this is a simple task to do.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

```
  $this->Student->recursive = -1;

          $joinoptions = array(
      //  $options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'students_subjects',
                'alias' => 'StudentsSubject',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'Student.id = StudentsSubject.student_id',
                 )
                 ),

            array('table' => 'subjects',
                'alias' => 'Subject',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'StudentsSubject.subject_id=Subject.id',
                 )
                 ),  

            );

            $fieldoptions =  array('Student.id,Student.last_name,Student.first_name,Student.address_street,Student.address_suburb,'
                                . 'Subject.name,Subject.id, StudentsSubject.id, Student.first_name,Student.last_name,Student.address_lat,Student.address_long,Student.tutor_gender_preference'
                               );

            $student=$this->Student->find('all',array(
               'conditions'=>   array( 'Student.id' => $student_id),

               'fields'=>$fieldoptions,
                'joins'=> $joinoptions,
              //  'group' => 'Student.id',
                'recursive' =>-1,

               )); 


array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '216',
            'last_name' => 'Ncc',
            'first_name' => 'Acc',
            'address_street' => '8 sdsdt',
            'address_suburb' => 'Hasdsdk',
            'address_lat' => 'xx',
            'address_long' => 'xx',
            'tutor_gender_preference' => 'No Preference'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'English: Year 7 - 10',
            'id' => '9'
        ),
        'StudentsSubject' => array(
            'id' => '531'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '216',
            'last_name' => 'Ncc',
            'first_name' => 'Acc',
            'address_street' => '8 sdsdt',
            'address_suburb' => 'Hasdsdk',
            'address_lat' => 'xx',
            'address_long' => 'xx',
            'tutor_gender_preference' => 'No Preference'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'Maths: Year 7 - 10',
            'id' => '16'
        ),
        'StudentsSubject' => array(
            'id' => '532'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '216',
            'last_name' => 'Ncc',
            'first_name' => 'Acc',
            'address_street' => '8 sdsdt',
            'address_suburb' => 'Hasdsdk',
            'address_lat' => 'xx',
            'address_long' => 'xx',
            'tutor_gender_preference' => 'No Preference'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'name' => 'Physics: Year 11',
            'id' => '28'
        ),
        'StudentsSubject' => array(
            'id' => '583'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I believe this would be achieved with an appropriate `recursive` value (perhaps 2?). Can you add the array this currently returns?